# How should viewportEvent be implemented in a QAbstractScrollArea?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm having a lot of problems getting the details right for my `QAbstractScrollArea`.  This is my current implementation of `viewportEvent`:

```
def viewportEvent(self, event):
    if event.type() in [QEvent.MouseButtonPress,
                        QEvent.MouseMove,
                        QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,
                        QEvent.ContextMenu,
                        QEvent.KeyPress,
                        QEvent.KeyRelease]:
        return self.my_viewport.event(event)

    if event.type() == QEvent.Resize:
        self.my_viewport.resizeEvent(event)
        return super().viewportEvent(event)

    if event.type() in [QEvent.UpdateLater,
                        QEvent.UpdateRequest]:
        self.my_viewport.event(event)
    if event.type() == QEvent.Paint:
        self.my_viewport.paintEvent(event)
    return super().viewportEvent(event)
```

The idea is to pass through (to the viewport widget) things like key and mouse presses.  Resize events need to be passed through and sent to the abstract-scroll-area itself?  What about the size for the scroll bars?  Shouldn't the resize event's size be changed.  If I don't pass paint events through, the viewport widget doesn't paint.

---

Minimum working example of broken QOpenGLWidget with QAbstractScrollArea:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAbstractScrollArea, QApplication, QMainWindow,
                             QOpenGLWidget)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scope_view_widget = ScrollingScopeView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scope_view_widget)

class ScopeView(QOpenGLWidget):

    def paintGL(self):
        super().paintGL()
        print("Painting")


class ScrollingScopeView(QAbstractScrollArea):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_my_viewport(ScopeView())

    def set_my_viewport(self, new_viewport):
        self.my_viewport = new_viewport
        self.setViewport(self.my_viewport)

    def viewportEvent(self, event):
        # Uncommenting this breaks painting.
        if event.type() == QEvent.Paint:
            self.my_viewport.paintEvent(event)
        return super().viewportEvent(event)


application = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

---

Filed as a Qt bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53269

Comment: It looks like you need to brush up on your understanding of how Qt implements `QAbstractScrollArea`. `viewportEvent()` need only be reimplemented when 1) you do *not* want an event to propagate to the viewport, 2) you want to modify an event before it reaches the viewport, 3) or you want to catch events firing to do something else with your scroll area.

Comment: @JonHarper If that's true, then why does the central widget not paint unless I explicitly forward the paint event?

Comment: @JonHarper And yes I do need to more than just brush up on how Qt works!  If you know how this should be done, please feel free to add an answer :)

Comment: Try commenting out the entire code block and call `setViewport()` with `self.my_viewport` as a parameter. The scroll area should do the rest.

Comment: @JonHarper I am calling `setViewport`.  If I comment out this method, painting stops.

Comment: Can you show where you do this? Is there a layout involved?

Comment: @JonHarper Done.  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I've added a new, correct answer that is basically the opposite of my previous. *sigh* At least I learned something. If you're okay with it, I'd like to delete my initial answer, as it is only going to confuse the drive-by reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer was absolutely wrong. Kudos to the OP for his investigation.

Per the docs:

> When inheriting QAbstractScrollArea, you need to do the following:
>
> - Control the scroll bars by setting their range, value, page step, and tracking their movements.
> - Draw the contents of the area in the viewport according to the values of the scroll bars.
> - Handle events received by the viewport in viewportEvent() - notably resize events.
> - Use viewport->update() to update the contents of the viewport instead of update() as all painting operations take place on the viewport.

Unless you need to do other event management, the very short `viewportEvent()` in your MCVE is **correct**. [Take a look at the code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractscrollarea.cpp) (a better look than I did) and you'll see that most events (including paint events) are not passed to the viewport. Curiously, the code does make an exception to properly resize `QOpenGLWidget`.

I realize now the logic behind **not** painting by default is to allow you to *update only the region of the viewport currently visible*.

In short, the below is fine. I would recommend checking to ensure the paint event only includes the rect currently visible (check the value of `rect()` in the paint event), otherwise you'll be painting areas not currently visible in your viewport.

```
def viewportEvent(self, event):
    # Uncommenting this breaks painting.
    if event.type() == QEvent.Paint:
        self.my_viewport.paintEvent(event)
    return super().viewportEvent(event)
```

Apologies for my screwup. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: No need to apologize!  Thanks for your help.